# Change computer name

Tags: c#, active-directory

We use Configuration managar to install operating systems, that for some genius reason does not have a simple way to set rules for machine names.

So im looking for a C# API that allows me to change the computer name ( NETBIOS) and change it in Active directory at the same time. I want to set the name AFTER im connected to AD so i can check if the machine had a old name and belonged to a none spesfic OU.

I have tried:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool SetComputerNameEx(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT NameType,string lpBuffer);
```

This one does change the local machine name, but this will corrupt the AD connection.

Comment: Changing the computer name requires a reboot.

Comment: That is true, but using the SetComputerNameEx it looses Active directory connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all Windows OSes since XP you can simply use the [command-line program NETDOM.EXE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298593) to change the computer name on both the machine itself and Active Directory... no programming required.

Comment: netdom is not available in windows 10

Answer (score 1):

```
string newName = "newName";

RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM", true).OpenSubKey("CurrentControlSet", true).OpenSubKey("Services", true).OpenSubKey("tcpip", true).OpenSubKey("Parameters", true);

key.SetValue("Hostname", newName);
key.SetValue("NV Hostname", newName);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, but i dont think that will work with active directory.